# How do I figure out the indexes of where a string was split?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 (Ruby 2.3).  I use the following to split a string based on a regular expression

```
my_string.split(/\W+/)
```

My question is, how can I get an equivalent array of numbers in which each number represents the index of where the splits occurred?  If no splits occurred, I would expect the array to only contain an element with “-1”.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the splitting regex matches a substring that has more than 1 character. \W+ could match " - " for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't want to split, you just want the indices?

```
a = []
"Hello stack overflow".scan(/\W+/){a<<Regexp.last_match.begin(0)}
a
#=> [5, 11]
```

An empty array would mean that no split occured.

Edit : Shorter version could be

```
"Hello stack overflow".enum_for(:scan, /\W+/).map{Regexp.last_match.begin(0)}
#=> [5, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) will split a string on substrings having multiple characters. The offset into the string of the beginning of each substring may not be sufficient. Both the start and end indices may be needed.

The following method returns an array of tuples, the first element of each tuple being the portion of the string returned by `strip`, the second being the index where that substring begins. Note only does this provide a way to compute the desired indices, but it also returns the substrings returned by `split`.

```
def split_with_offsets(str, r)
  indices = []
  str.scan(r) { indices << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  str.split(r).zip(indices << str.size).map { |s,ndx| [s, ndx-s.size] }
end
```

With this information it is straightforward to obtain an array of ranges, each range being the offsets of a substring on which the strip is split.

```
def gaps(str, r)
  split_with_offsets(str, r).each_cons(2).map { |(s,f), (_,lp1)| f+s.size..lp1-1 }
end
```

Here are two examples.

*#1*

```
str = "Hello stack overflow"
r = /\W+/

split_with_offsets(str, r)
  #=> [["Hello", 0], ["stack", 6], ["overflow", 12]] 
gaps(str, r)
  #=> [5..5, 11..11]
```

*#2*

```
str = "I | cannot | wait | for |    the election |to |be  | over"
r = /\s*\|\s*/ 

split_with_offsets(str, r)
  #=> [["I", 0], ["cannot", 4], ["wait", 13], ["for", 20], ["the election", 29],
  #    ["to", 43], ["be", 47], ["over", 53]] 
gaps(str, r)
  #=> [1..3, 10..12, 17..19, 23..28, 41..42, 45..46, 49..52]
```